# Google SignInButton cannot resolve

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

Title, I can't add the packages needed to add google sign in

Gradle 4.4, Gradle plugin 3.1.3, Google services 4.0.1

Added Firebase dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
...
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

downloaded `GooglePlayServices` SDK as well. I still don't have the `SignInButton` (get 'SignInButton button cannot resolve')

what am I missing

Answer (score 0):

There might be some other issue. I think you don't need to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.

I used the same `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'` version just now and I am able to get `SignInButton`. Below is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Screenshot from layout xml file:

[image]

**Can you confirm that you are able to build your project successfully?** If not then please make sure your project is built successfully without any error and then try to add `SignInButton`. You will get it.

For more information, follow this official link : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Comment: I can add the google SignInButton in XML, it even shows in design tab and it builds.
I can't however use SignInButton type to reference it in java, so it won't build if I try.

Comment: @John as I mentioned in the first line of my answer, problem is somewhere else. If you don't find any issue in XML layout for SignInButton then there should not be any error in Java as well. By the way, can you add your Java code like how you are trying to call `SignInButton` there. I am able to build code successfully.

Comment: OK, I just redid the whole project. It looks like a bug with android studio or a mix up with the packages (was switching versions everywhere). thanks!

Comment: @John see I told you issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @John If you think my efforts helped you then please upvote and accept my answer.